# Impressão em Impressora matricial com WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Como eu faço para imprimir meus tickets em uma impressora matricial(LX300) a partir de rotinas feitas em WPF C#? Tem alguma coisa específica para isso? Um drive ou plugin?

Answer (score 1):

**Opção 1=** 
Monte um arquivo de texto, e envie para a impressora, copiando o arquivo para ela. Ex:

*no C#:*

```
File.Copy("arquivo.txt","\\servidor\lx300");
```

ou

```
File.Copy("arquivo.txt","lpt1");
```

**Opção 2=** 
Utilize um gerador de relatório, crystal, report viewer, entre outros, e mande para impressora normalmente, pelo spooler do windows.

**Opção 3=** 
Gere um `PrintDocument` e envie para impressora, por um `PrintDialog`. Segue código comentado:

```
//Fila de linhas que devem ser impressas
Queue<string> filaLinhas = new Queue<string>();


PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
//Evento PrintPage do PrintDocument
p.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    //Define a fonte utilizada para impressão
    Font printFont = new Font("Consolas", 11);
    float linesPerPage = 0;
    float yPos = 0;
    int count = 0;
    float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
    float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
    string line = null;

    //Calcular o número de linhas por página
    linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

    //Imprime cada linha da página
    while (count < linesPerPage && filaLinhas.Count >0 )
    {
        line = filaLinhas.Dequeue();
        yPos = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
        ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, 0, yPos, new StringFormat());
        count++;
    }

    //Se existir mais linhas, gera outra página
    if (line != null && filaLinhas.Count >0)
        ev.HasMorePages = true;
    else
        ev.HasMorePages = false;
};

//Exibe o dialogo de impressão (se não for necessário, só pular o ShowDialog e chamar o .Print(); (Lembre-se de definir a impressora, ou será utilizada a padrão do windows)
PrintDialog diag = new PrintDialog();
diag.Document = p;
diag.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "LX 300";
if (diag.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    p.Print();
}
```

Comment: Meu problema Rovan, é que eu não tenho impressora para testes e meu cliente fica a 230Km de onde eu estou. Vou nele apenas para instalar o que tenho que instalar. A impressão quero deixar para o final, mas preciso saber como fazer. Lembrando que uso WPF para esses projetos. Esse código roda no WPF? Não testei ainda, devido a problema aqui, mas ao resolver, vou testar o código apenas, se compila ou não. Esse código parece windows form.

Comment: Instale uma impressora virtual, o windows já vem com a XPS e você pode instalar uma PDF por exemplo, nesses casos, vai pedir pra salvar o arquivo de impressão, mas é bom para fazer testes. Mesmo usando WPF, você pode usar a biblioteca do `System.Windows.Forms` que contém o `PrintDialog` e acredito ter um equivalente (no WPF). O `PrintDocument` pertence à `System.Drawing.Printing` então creio já estar disponível.

Comment: Ok, farei isso e ao ter o resultado, posto para todos.

Comment: Algum progresso @pnet ?

Comment: Rovann, dei uma parada, pois preciso terminar dois métodos que faz o cálculo dos cereais(Soja e Milho) e depois sim, que vou pegar firme na impressão, pois o que vai ser impresso é o resultado desse cálculo. Preciso da impressão ainda essa semana.